# Osprey Atmos AG 50 raincover

Tags: backpacking, backpacks

I have Osprey Atmos AG 50 and I am trying to buy a rain cover for it. There are two sizes in Ultralight rain cover model.One is 'M' size (upto 50 L) and another is 'L' size (50-75 L). Have anyone bought 'L' size cover? I am bit concerned with 'M' size because when the bag is fully loaded will it cover well? Is it better to go for 'L'?

Comment: How about asking Osprey? That would give a more definitive answer than random strangers on the internet...

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I just received reply from Osprey saying that 'L' would be too big for the Atmos AG 50.

Comment: You can make that an answer, especially since it contradicts Charlie's answer. Then, after (IIRC) 2 days you can mark it as the 'correct' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** I just received reply from Osprey saying that 'L' would be too big for the Atmos AG 50.According to them 'M' size would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Either should be fine, the M size may not fully cover it if you have the backpack stuffed to the max.

On the other hand, as of right now **it's a difference of 0.2 oz + $3 between the two**, so if you are worried that much about it, then just get the bigger one. The other advantage of the bigger cover is if you ever need a bigger pack for longer trips you already have one.

The bottom line is that the difference between the two is pretty negligible so I would just get the bigger one.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I just received reply from Osprey saying that 'L' would be too big for the Atmos AG 50.